# Trying to plot a periodic function, gets ValueError

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to plot a function f. Under is the code that I have.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def f(x):
    if -np.pi < x < np.pi/2:
        return 0
    elif np.pi/2 < x < np.pi:
        return 1
    else:
        print("Error")

x = np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, 1000)

plt.plot(x, f(x))
plt.show()
```

Could someone help me explain why I get the error message "ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()", and how do I fix it?

Have been trying to look on the internet for a solution to my error message, but I do not understand how to solve it.

Comment: `x` has 1000 items. What should `if -np.pi < x` mean?

Comment: I am trying to plot a periodic function with a periode 2pi where on interval (-pi, pi) the function f(x) = 0, if -pi < x < pi/2 or f(x) = 1, if pi/2 < x < pi

Comment: "Have been trying to look on the internet for a solution to my error message, but I do not understand how to solve it." To be clear, you tried copying and pasting the error message into a search engine, and you found the linked duplicate, right? Then what, exactly?

Comment: You did not understand @MichaelButscher's question. Let us say that `x` is an array with two elements, like `[-10, 0]`,  **What do you think the result should be** when we try `-np.pi < x`? Why?

Comment: Please especially see my answer on the linked duplicate, especially the section titled "Fixing if statements".

Comment: Think about the thing @DanielTran is trying to say. We can compare 10 with 0, but what is meant by comparing a list [10,10] with 0? What should be the answer?  To help you out with your error, Try using maps for this. Replacing the plot line by plt.plot(x, list(map(f, x))) should work.

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for something like:

```
plt.plot(x, [f(v) for v in x])
```

You need to pass each single element to the function rather than the whole array, otherwise the comparison with a number isn't meaningful.